# How to deal with two game modes in the same script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If for instance I have a game which consists of just a single scene, and in that scene I make the user chose between the normal play mode or the tutorial play mode. The game has 4 different objects: a ball, 4 squares and a squarecontroller. In the tutorial mode i want to provide the user with a pointing arrow while pausing the game and continue after the user pressed the  object being pointed at. Should I make a script for the normal mode and another one for the tutorial mode, make one script and check if a tutorial boolean is true or false in every function (boolean should be true if user pressed the tutorial button) or do some kind of preprocessing?

In the squarescript for example:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D () {
 if (isTutorial) {
    PauseGame();
    arrow.position = GetRelativePosition();
    arrow.setActive(true);
 } else {
  if (canCollide) {
    score++;
  } else {
    GameOver();
   }
 }
```

In the ballscript:

```
void OnMouseDown () {
   if (!isTutorial) {
      return;
   }

   ResumeGame();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By structuring these behaviours inside if statements, it makes the code hard to understand and work with. Imagine what this will look like if you decide you want one of the squares to increase the players score AND show a tutorial arrow.

Split the behaviours into separate objects. For the square it could be something like a `TutorialCollisionHandler`, `ScoreCollisionHandler`and `HazardCollisionHandler`. Then you can create different squares simply by changing which collision handlers are added to them, you don't even need to write any code!

Now depending on which mode the user picks, you can just use a different mix of squares. The same principle can be used with other tutorial or game specific behaviour.

Comment: So the TutorialCollisionHandler, ScoreCollisionHandler and HazardCollisionHandler are seperate scripts which can be added by code?

Comment: MonoBehaviours that you can add to the Square GameObject just like a collider or a rigidbody etc.

Answer (score 3):

We know nothing of your game so it's hard to answer. But as a rule of thumb: The less you have to type, the better. Also consider what will happen if you need to add new functionality to the game, will you have to go back and change tons in your code? 
If so, you are most likely not writing *good* code.

As an attempt to give a concrete answer I'd say you should make an inheritance, create a class `Level` and make sub classes `Tutorial` and `FreePlay` or similar, that inherits from `Level`.

Then you can add all "general" functionality in the base class and the specific things goes in the sub classes

Comment: My game is a pretty simple game, containing 4 different kind of objects and around 6 scripts. I pretty much need the scripts to act differently based on if it's in tutorial mode or normal mode.

Comment: OK so put it in a variable what mode the game play is, and then based on the game mode you can do different things. Like this answer says, you don't provide much and it's hard to know what you want.

Comment: I have added more information, please inform me about any more information you might need.

Comment: If you are asking about "best practice" then this answer tells you what you need to know. The size/scope of the project certainly doesn't matter if the goal is to write in good practice. 

If you are asking about a specific problem with either of the solutions, It's still unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @user24028 Sorry, didn't realize you had gotten an answer. But another rule of thumb in object oriented programming is to divide everything in as many classes & methods as possible. It makes your code easier to tweak, change, debug and add to, and it also makes the code easier to read.